# Get activated route from angular 2 routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Hi so I have declared my route with the id like this `{path: 'spreadsheet/:id', component: ContactParent}` so here I can get the `id` by using `ActivatedRoute` but how I can get `spreadsheet`, if I do `this.router.url` it gives me `spreadsheet/20` but I only need `spreadsheet`

Comment: Not sure what's the point, but can't you simply use `substring` method?

Comment: @Pijotrek I can but I was thinking if there is anything similar like `ActivatedRoute`  which I can use

Comment: I always console.log(route) and then drill down into the output to find what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute ) {
    console.log(route.pathFromRoot[1].snapshot.url[0].path);
}
```

If you go to, for example, http://localhost:4200/spreadsheet/3, the above code will log "spreadsheet"

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'; // import Router from @angular/router

constructor(private router: Router){ // private member of Router
 const currentPageUrl = router.url; // router.url contain the active route info
 console.log('Activated router is ' + currentPageUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you should be able to get the route from the `ActivatedRoute`, there may be times you want to get the route from your bootstrapped component. In this case you can use angular's [Location Service](https://alligator.io/angular/location-service/) and call `location.path()` to get the requested route.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
<a actionLink='['/list',id]'>link</a>


    constructor( private _route: ActivatedRoute ){ 
    let id=this._route.snapshot.param['id'];
    }
```

You have to import the ActivatedRoute.

Comment: Please consider using complete code snippets.